# Convert -3 (signed) to 3 (unsigned) in asm

Tags: assembly, masm, unsigned, signed

Input are interger numbers and after calculation, i need the output is real number. Like when I enter 1,23,123 and the ouput of second calculation is -33.-3 while the actual result is -33.3. How can I convert -3 to 3? I'm beginner in assembly so I hope someone can help me. Thanks for your help.

```
    include \masm32\include\masm32rt.inc
    
    .code

start:
    call main
    exit
main proc
    LOCAL var1:DWORD
    LOCAL var2:DWORD
    LOCAL var3:DWORD
    LOCAL tong:DWORD
    LOCAL result:DWORD
    LOCAL remainder:DWORD
    LOCAL a:DWORD
    LOCAL b:DWORD
    LOCAL e:DWORD
    LOCAL d:DWORD
    mov var1, sval(input("Enter number 1: "))
    mov var2, sval(input("Enter number 2: "))
    mov var3, sval(input("Enter number 3: "))
    mov result, 0
    mov e, 10    

    print chr$("v1 + v2 + v3 = ")
    mov eax, var1
    add eax, var2
    add eax, var3
    mov tong, eax
    print str$(tong)
    print chr$(13,10)

    print chr$("[(v1 * v2) - v3] / 3 = ")
    mov eax, var1
    cdq
    Imul var2
    cdq
    mov a, eax
    sub eax, var3
    mov b, eax
    mov edx, 0
    mov eax, b
    cdq
    mov ecx, 3
    Idiv ecx
    mov result, eax
    mov remainder, edx
    
    mov eax, remainder
    Imul e
    mov d, eax
    mov edx, 0
    mov eax, d
    cdq
    mov ecx, 3
    idiv ecx
    mov remainder, eax

    mov al, byte remainder
    mov ah, 0
    add ax, 1234
    mov remainder, ax
    
    print str$(result)
    print chr$(".")
    print str$(remainder)
    ret

main endp

end start
```

Comment: Check if the number is negative, if it is, negate it.

Comment: How would you do it in , say, C, Java, or other?